# Is there a way to define a variable in HTML?

Tags: html

I have some text that is pretty repetitive on a web page. It can change from time to time. If I write it in 10 different places then need to change it, I have to go through the html and change it in every single place.

As an example of what I'm looking for, instead of writing "Stack Overflow is the best website ever" over and over again, is there a way that I could write something like variable:stackoverflow="Stack Overflow is the best website ever" in one place then write "stackoverflow" in the 10 different places I need the text. That way if/when I need to change it I can just change it in the one place, not the 10 different places on the page.

Comment: not with HTML but with Javascript (angularjs 1 could be the best approach ) or PHP,

Comment: Use JS or library like Jquery or ReactJS or MVC framework such as AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

No.

Typically this problem is solved by generating HTML using a programming language, often in combination with a template language.

This can be done either at:

- build time, generating static files and uploading them to a server), e.g. using a tool such as [assemble](http://assemble.io/)
- server side (on demand when the page is requested), e.g. using [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) and the programming language of your choice
- client side (using JavaScript running in the browser … although this isn't considered [best practise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare such variables in HTML. I guess, it's the best way, to use PHP. PHP is executed by the server and a HTML-Document will be send to the client. JavaScript is executed by the client and some users denie the JavaScript-execution.

In my opinion it's he best way is to use PHP.

For display texts in PHP, you should check out the website [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/)